# Flutter - Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: instance, future

I'm building a weather app for practice and I'm getting following error:

```
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: []("weather")
```

And this is where I think it comes from:

```
    void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
        var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
        String cityName = weatherData['name'];
        double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
        temperature = temp.toInt();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create a class for my Data i got from my api call:

```
class WeatherData {
  final int conditionID;
  final String cityName;
  final double temperature;

  const WeatherData({
    required this.conditionID,
    required this.cityName,
    required this.temperature,
  });

  factory WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return WeatherData(
      conditionID: json['weather'][0]['id'],
      cityName: json['name'],
      temperature: json['main']['temp'],
    );
  }
}
```

And then use it in updateUI() like this:

```
void updateUI(WeatherData weatherData) {
    var condition = weatherData.conditionID;
    String cityName = weatherData.cityName;
    double temp = weatherData.temperature;
    temperature = temp.toInt();
  }
```

As always the documentation helped me a lot:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data